# Moving cursor to cell below in google sheets automatic when datainput amount = 1

Tags: google-sheets

Im making a registration kind of google sheets project, where the amount of input is quite high, however the input in each cell only needs to be 1 number. It would therefore be usefull to have a script, which made the cursor jump to the cell below after input of 1 number.

```
efunction onEdit(e) {
var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
var col = activeCell.getColumn();
var row = activeCell.getRow();
var value = activeCell.getValue();
if (value.length == 1) {
 sheet.getRange(row + 1, col).activate();
  }
}
```

However this only makes the cursor jump to the cell below the one which the input has been made, when another action is made, like clicking on 3rd cell. therefore not making the registrations easier.

Hope you can help.

Comment: Not sure if you want it to jump to the cell below the one you're in as you're typing, or if it's to jump when you hit tab or enter. Anyway, I don't think there is a method that watches it as you're type, but rather when the value you type gets registered.

Comment: If I understand correctly you want to be able to read the moment when users start typing so that they are limited to only introduce 1 character in each cell and then move the active cell to the next one, correct? If not, can you provide a minimal reproducible example so that we can get a better understanding of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Correct, when the user types in 1 character, I would like the active cell to become the one below.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Sheets `onEdit(e)` trigger only runs when the user completes their data entry in a cell, usually by pressing **Enter** or **Tab**. You cannot watch individual characters as they are being entered.

What you can do, however, is let the user enter longer strings of digits in the cell, and when **Enter** is finally pressed, put each one of those digits in a cell of its own. You can then move the selection after the last digit that was thus filled down.

To do that, use `String.split()`, like this:

```js
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* Watches column Sheet1!A2:A as it is edited and splits digit strings such
* as 321654 or 321 654 into single digits 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, and puts each
* digit in a cell of its own, stacking them vertically, starting at the
* cell where the digit string was entered.
* Moves the selection to the cell after the cell where last digit was put.
* Will happily overwrite values in cells under the cell that was edited.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 2 January 2023
  //  - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74986570/13045193
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window.');
  if (!e.value
    || e.value.match(/[^\d\s]/i)
    || e.range.columnStart !== 1 // column A
    || e.range.rowStart < 2
    || !e.range.getSheet().getName().match(/^(Sheet1)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  const numbers = e.value
    .replace(/\s/g, '')
    .split('')
    .map(n => [n]);
  e.range
    .offset(0, 0, numbers.length, 1)
    .setValues(numbers)
    .offset(numbers.length, 0, 1, 1)
    .activate();
}
```

Comment: This works marvels for the project! Thanks for the creative solution!

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that it is not possible to recognize what the users are typing until the edit is completely made. What you can do instead is to recognize if the value they have introduced is longer than 1 character and edit the cell by taking only the first character of what they introduce.

You can try the following script:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = e.source;
  var val = e.value;
  var r = e.range;

  if(val.length>1)
  {
    var x  = val.substring(0,1);
  }
  r.setValue(x);
}
```

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)
- [setValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue)

Comment: Hmm... if one needs to edit the spreadsheet in any other way but entering single-digit numbers, this function will make the spreadsheet pretty difficult to use. Any and all values you try to put in _any_ cell in _any_ tab will get converted to a one-character text string.

Comment: You can limit the function to validate a specific range so that it runs only when it recognizes the desired range.